# How can I make a histogram of a row from a table?

Tags: r, self-study, distributions, data-visualization, histogram

I have a table where each row contains the grade distribution of a class in a certain year. For example, one row may look like this:

```
A   B   C   D  E  

127 109 225 108 85
```

How can i make a histogram from this row? I have tried the hist() function, but it gives me an error:
Error in hist.default(v2013[6:10]) : 'x' must be numeric
Then I tried
hist(as.numeric(v2013[6:10])), but it gives me a messed up plot:

[image]

Could someone please tell me how I can make a histogram of this data correctly? I just started learning statistics and R, and I am trying to learn both at the same time, so I apologize for the noob question. Could you also tell me how to get the grades 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' and 'E' on the x-axis.

EDIT:
My table looks like this:

```
year  subject F% females% %A A B C D E Afem Bfem Cfem Dfem Efem
2004    1   9.8     20.6    13.0    48  54  65  74  83  12  16  10  15 17
2005    1   11.2    24.4    8.5     31  55  56  57  113 10  17  16  12  28
2005    2   10.8    24.5    7.6     49  85  143 133 148 7   18  41  37  32
2006    1   12.2    26.6    8.9     37  59  138 65  43  12  11  41  18  10
```

I was interested in columns 6 to 10 in row 1, so I did:

data = v2013[1, 6:10]

This gave me the output

```
A   B   C   D  E  

127 109 225 108 85
```

Then I tried the following:

```
data = v2013[1, 6:10] 
colnames(data) = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") 
barplot(data, main="Column Chart", xlab="Grades")
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in barplot.default(data, main = "Column Chart", xlab = "Grades") :    'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

Comment: Use barplot() function. Histogram is for numeric variables.

Comment: You might be better off on R-help for programming questions in R.

Comment: do you have a link to R-help, or is it another part of Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is not exactly a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), it's a column chart, the [function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html) `barplot` can help. I don't have your data, but you can adapt the code below:

```
# Simple Bar Plot 
data = t(data.frame(c(10,20,30)))
colnames(data) = c("A","B", "C")
barplot(data, main="Column Chart", xlab="Grades")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have edited my question to show what my table looks like. I tried doing the following based on your example:

Comment: data = v2013[6:10]
colnames(data) = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
barplot(data, main="Column Chart", xlab="Grades")

but I get the following error:
Error in barplot.default(data, main = "Column Chart", xlab = "Grades") : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix

Comment: Try using `as.matrix(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

The plot that you want to do is *not* a histogram, it's a [**bar plot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart). Bar plot shows on one axis some categories or groups, and use rectangular bars with lengths proportional to some value like their counts etc. In case of [histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) you also have bars, but you do not show predefined groups, but rather use statistical procedure to pack your data into some number of bins (e.g. age groups).